# Nginx not redirecting properly

Tags: linux, nginx, centos7

I'm a bit confused, I really thought this was going to be a simple 5 minute task, but no. I followed the documentation for a redirect, but I can't get it working properly, it is just appending multiples of the new url (not sure how many, but I counted at least 10 off the edge of the url bar) to the original one. Here is my server block config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name old.i.p.address;
        return 301 new.i.p.address/redirect_page/;

        location ~ /si/home/0/ {
                 return 301 /si/home/;
                 }

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static {
                      alias /home/rob/pcc_django/staticfiles/;
                      }

        location / {
                 proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                 proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        }
    }
```

Apologies if indentation is wrong, it is formatted correctly on my machine, I haven't worked out how to keep formatting in code blocks on this site correctly.

I have tried multiple versions with and without "http://" at the start of the new ip address, I've tried it with and without the "/homepage" also. I've also tried to use "rewrite" as initially I just wanted a permanent redirect, but this was the only iteration that would allow ngingx server to start and it's giving strange results in the url bar:

```
old.i.p.address/homepage/new.i.p.address/redirect_page/new.i.p.address/redirect_page/new.i.p.address/redirect_page/new.i.p.address/redirect_page/new.i.p.address/redirect_page/new.i.p.address/redirect_page/new.i.p.address/redirect_page/new.i.p.address/redirect_page/new.i.p.address/redirect_page/...etc ad infinitum
```

How can I fix this please?

Comment: Are `old.i.p.address` and `new.i.p.address` just IPv4 addresses or they are domain names?

Comment: Yes correct, they are just IPv4 addresses, this is an internal work website.

Comment: The `new.i.p.address/redirect_page/` string is treated by browser as **relative** URI on the same server giving you that endless loop with concatenation of `new.i.p.address/redirect_page/` on every iteration. For example, if you'd had a `return 301 /new.i.p.address/redirect_page/;` rule, that string would be treated as absolute URI giving you the same address on every iteration. The only right way is to use `http://` (or `https://`) prefix. As already said by @emptyhua, 301 permanent redirects are cached by the browsers so you should clear your cache or try from the incognito window.

Comment: @IvanShatsky Thank you so much, that solved it, if you could change this to an answer and not a comment I would like to accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `new.i.p.address/redirect_page/` string is treated by browser as relative URI on the same server giving you that endless loop with the concatenation of `new.i.p.address/redirect_page/` part on every iteration. For example, if you'd had a `return 301 /new.i.p.address/redirect_page/;` rule, that string would be treated as absolute URI giving you the same address on every iteration. The only right way is to use `http://` (or `https://`) prefix. As already said by @emptyhua, HTTP 301 permanent redirects are cached by the browsers so you should clear your cache or try from the incognito window.

Answer (score 0):

301 redirect will be cached in browser, you could [clear the browser cache](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop), and try `return 301 http://new.i.p.address/redirect_page/;` again.